# How to parse a CSV natively in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

On **Windows Phone**: Is there a **Native CSV Parser** in the Framework? Is there some equivalent to **TextFieldParser** that is in the **Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO** namespace?

As shown in this posting: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/

If possible, I want to read the CSV using some native Class, not create again some code to read it.

Comment: Why dont you write your own parser? All you need to do is scan the string character by character. When you see a quote you keep scanning until the next one and same applies to the comma(excep the ones in the quote.)

Comment: Not duplicate, because it is on Windows Phone 8.1, and reffers to a Native CSV Parser.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer If you read the docs on the TextFieldParser, it is not available on Windows Phone platforms.

Comment: @Tony Use [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper). Its supported for Portable Class Library.